# Non-obtrusive version control

Tags: version-control

I'm looking for a way to put several of my projects under version control, with the least amount of filesystem-level obtrusiveness.

The rationale for this is because my dev environment is mostly FS-based (total commander + notepad++ + wing + scripting tools with python), so FS changes (including, and most annoyingly the .svn directory of subversion) *hurts* .

My version control requirements are very basic: commit/rollback/browse ,and good utility support.

Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Have you ever considered to actually *hide* hidden directories and files? I've been doing that for years now, didn't catch any kitty-eating malware that hid in hidden files and overall my folders look a lot cleaner since I can also hide arbitrary folders I rarely need. This takes care of `.svn` directories pretty nicely. And for the rare case I actually need to touch a hidden dir there's always Ctrl+H in Far, I'm sure Total Commander has something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial, git and Bazaar all just put a single directory at the root of the project.  All of them are plenty powerful enough to handle the requirements you listed.

Mercurial and Bazaar are written in Python, and you mentioned you use Python for scripting, so picking one of them could be an advantage if you ever want to look at how they work or write scripts that use them.

EDIT: Here's some more information on [writing Mercurial hooks in Python](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id403443).

Comment: And the Mercurial version of git ready would be (please excuse the shameless self-promotion) [hgtip.com](http://hgtip.com/)

Comment: Ugh, SO's Markdown support in comments is terrible, sorry.

Comment: Just want to thank you for your recommendation -ultimately, I went with git+github, and it's been working like a breeze! So, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Bazaar has just a .bzr directory at the top level. It also works on all platforms natively (Git is still somewhat hokey on Windows). I find it simpler than Git too.

Community wiki so others can add more info about Bazaar.

These guides should help you get started with bazaar:

[Bazaar in five minutes](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/mini-tutorial/index.html)

[Bazaar User Guide](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-guide/index.html)

Comment: git works well on Windows (msysgit project). Mercurial and git also use only top-level directory.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial only uses a .hg directory in the top top directory and it has [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home) that makes it easy to use in Windows.